# SonataAdmin How to edit buttons in list view

Tags: symfony, twig, sonata-admin

In my `Symfony` project, I use `SonataAdminBundle` for my dashboard.

I want to modify/edit buttons contained in my list view.

For example, for the button Edit, i want to change the icon `"fa-edit"` to another icon.

To make that, I search to edit the `edit_button.html.twig` which contains :

```html
{% if admin.canAccessObject('edit', object) and admin.hasRoute('edit') %}
    <li>
        <a class="sonata-action-element" href="{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('edit', object) }}">
            <i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            {{ 'link_action_edit'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}
        </a>
    </li>
{% endif %}
```

And I try to change :

```html
<i class="fa fa-edit" [...]
for
<i class="fa fa-cog" [...].
```

But it's not working... Any idea ?

Thanks for all !

Comment: I don't recommend you to directly modify the vendors. In this [documentation] it shows you how to correctly customize Sonata templates. However, if you really want to change this icon in the vendor, the template for the list view edition button is located in : `vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Resources/views/CRUD/list__action_edit.html.twig`

Comment: What is the path to the file you are trying to edit? What version of Symfony are you using? Have you cleared the cache?